# PHP for each arrray value second loop array key reset

Tags: php

I have array where

`category_id[0]` belongs to `product_id[1]` array

and

`category_id[1]` belongs to `product_id[2]` array

i run a foreach loop and inner foreach i use array_values to reset

i get the errors:

```
Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in 
Warning:  array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in 
Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Below is the array:

```
[category_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => cat1
            [1] => cat2
        )

    [product_id] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => prod1
                    [2] => prod2
                    [3] => prod3
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [2] => prod4
                    [3] => prod5
                )

        )

<?
foreach($_REQUEST['category_id'] as $key=>$value)
    {
    if(!empty($value))
    {
    mysql_query( "insert into category(category_id) values('".$_REQUEST['category_id'][$key]."')");
    $cat_id = mysql_insert_id();
    echo mysql_error();

    foreach(array_values($_REQUEST['product_id'][$key]) as $key1=>$value1)
    {



            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `product` (category_id,`prod_id`) VALUES ('".$cat_id."','".$value1."')");


    }
    }

   }
?>
```

Comment: Which part of the error messages is not clear to you? What is your question? Only sharing that you get some error message does not qualify as a programming question. Can you explain why you access an array at the undedinfed index 0? What's the use of that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your indexing. The `category_id` array starts at 0, while the `product_id`
starts at 1. So in the first iteration of the second loop you really put a null into
`array_values`

The error messages really tells you this, look at the notice before the two warnings.